# SQL, Is there a way allowing aggregation of data on multiple active periods based on start and end date fields?

Tags: sql-server

I am still new to SQL and data manipulation and I have no idea if it is possible as I have not come across anything from  searching that is the same. I am trying to aggregate data based on a active period between a start and end date. My current code that I have included should hopefully give an idea on the sort of aggregation I would like to perform.

I have tried to search for a way to do this in SQL or Powerbi but so far have come up short. Most of the examples I found are to perform calculations on a single column rather than the entire dataset. My original idea was to do a calculated column giving a list of months active but I failed to then aggregate on that enough to condense down the very large data set.

```
SELECT [Group ID], [User], [Location], [category], [Setup Date], [End Date], Count([Name]) AS 'Number of Names'
Avg([Duration in Weeks]) AS 'Avg duration',Avg([Days since last production]) AS 'Avg days since last production',Avg([Losses]) AS 'Avg losses',
ROUND(AVG([Number produced]/NULLIF([duration in weeks],0)),2) AS Productivity
FROM [Summary].[dbo].[Summary$]
Group BY [Group ID], [User], [Location], [Category], [Setup Date], [End Date]
```

For example if the set up date is "2017-01-09" and the end date is "2017-03-30" I would like to be able to aggregate this data in Jan 2018, Feb 2018 and Mar 2018 data all in the same table. I hope I have given enough information and explained clearly but please let me know if I need to provide anything else.

[Small snippet of raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g46xj.png)

Comment: If you provide your database schema or some sample data with schema, then it is more helpful to find the appropriate solution.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have added a small section of my sample data. I am working of a single flat file so I am unsure of what I would add by putting in a schema? Please let me know if it would be beneficial and I can do some research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CTE to create your periods

```
DECLARE @yearfrom int = 2017, @yearto int = 2019
;WITH months AS (
        SELECT 1 AS MonthNum, DATENAME(Month,DATEFROMPARTS(1,1,1)) AS MonthName
        UNION ALL
        SELECT MonthNum + 1, DATENAME(Month,DATEFROMPARTS(1, MonthNum + 1, 1)) AS MonthName
        FROM months
        WHERE MonthNum <= 11
    ),
    years as (
        SELECT @yearfrom as year
        union all
        select year + 1 
        from years where year < @yearto
    ),
    dates as (
        SELECT Year, MonthNum, MonthName, DATEFROMPARTS(Year, MonthNum, 1) AS DateStart, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEFROMPARTS(Year, MonthNum, 1)) AS DateEnd
        FROM years
        CROSS JOIN months
    )
SELECT d.year, d.MonthNum, d.MonthName, [Group ID], [User], [Location], [category], Count([Name]) AS 'Number of Names'
Avg([Duration in Weeks]) AS 'Avg duration',Avg([Days since last production]) AS 'Avg days since last production',Avg([Losses]) AS 'Avg losses',
ROUND(AVG([Number produced]/NULLIF([duration in weeks],0)),2) AS Productivity
FROM 
DATES d
LEFT JOIN [Summary].[dbo].[Summary$] ON 
    ([Setup Date] >= d.DateStart AND [Setup Date] < d.DateEnd)
    OR ([End Date] >= d.DateStart AND [End Date] < d.DateEnd)
Group BY d.year, d.monthnum, d.monthname, [Group ID], [User], [Location], [Category]
```

Comment: Thank you, from a quick go this looks to be doing the job and the date table is defiantly useful. I think I may be losing some data somewhere though but I will need to spend some time looking into. I will post back when I have a clear idea of what the issue could be.